# ASP.NET User Control declaration in designer.cs file

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does ASP.NET auto-generated .designer code have the incorrect type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331839/why-does-asp-net-auto-generated-designer-code-have-the-incorrect-type)

On my .aspx page, I have the following declaration to user my user control:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="ProductCategoryMenu" Src="~/Resources/Common/Controls/productCategoryMenu.ascx" %>

<uc:ProductCategoryMenu ID="ProductCategoryMenu" runat="server" />
```

Whenever the .designer file autogenerates, it declares

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.UserControl ProductCategoryMenu;
```

instead of the actual type of my user control.  Is there a way I can change that so I don't always have to open the .designer.cs file and correct it?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331839/why-does-asp-net-auto-generated-designer-code-have-the-incorrect-type) out - I think it will solve your issue. It's about helping the application resolve the `~` correctly.

Comment: Yup, that sounds right.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to manually edit the Designer file.

Comment: Yes, that's the point.  It doesn't seem to be generating correctly.

Comment: Mike,

Check this article:

http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/707067.aspx

Sometimes it can be cause by a name conflict with another file. Usually when I get really desperate, I zap the temp files (you may have to stop IIS to do this). Zap and re-create the UC. Also, check the compile properties in VS. Are you using a WAP? Reason I ask is because there are known problems when using UCs with the website project model:

http://west-wind.com/weblog/posts/3016.aspx

Comment: this did not fix the problem.  It seems inconsistent.  An explanation would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for you might be to remove the variable declaration from the MyPage.designer.cs into the MyPage.cs. It should normally not re-declare the variable into the MyPage.designer.cs.

Tell me if that fix your issue.

Comment: Yeah, I assume that will fix the issue, but it's just weird that it's so inconsistent.