# DotNetNuke DDRMenu set NodeSelector in code behind

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, ddrmenu

I'm using DDRMenu in DotNetNuke to select a menu node from my site structure and display only a subnode in a specific navigation in my template

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="MENU" Src="~/DesktopModules/DDRMenu/Menu.ascx" %>
<dnn:MENU ID="MenuFooter" MenuStyle="MenuFooter" IncludeHidden="true" NodeSelector="FooterNavigation,0,1" runat="server" ></dnn:MENU>
```

Now I want to be able to set the NodeSelector attribute in the code behind file, because I want to be able to dynamically set the value on Page_Load

```
// load footer navigation node from a config file
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var footerNode = Config.Instance.Navigation.FooterNode;
     MenuFooter.NodeSelector = footerNode + ",0,1";
}
```

But this doesn't work, as there is no NodeSelector attribute on System.Web.UI.UserControl.

> Error 'System.Web.UI.UserControl' does not contain a definition for 'NodeSelector' and no extension method 'NodeSelector' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.UserControl' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Projects\eWolf2012\dev\DNN\Portals_default\Skins\JWEwolfSkin2012\Simple.ascx.cs 141 24  JWEwolfSkin2012

Is there any way to achieve this?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the Menu.ascx in DDRMenu inherits from the DDRMenu `SkinObject`:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" EnableViewState="false" Inherits="DotNetNuke.Web.DDRMenu.SkinObject" %>
```

Since you are talking about changing the code behind I guess that you are using a custom control that embeds the Menu.ascx. In which case you should be able to access the `NodeSelector` property since it exists in the `SkinObject` class.

What I am suspecting is happening is that your control type is not loaded correctly by the designer, and that it falls back on the `UserControl` type which doesn't have the `NodeSelector` property.

Try the following:

- Include the DDRMenu assembly in your current project (because it won't load the type if it doesn't find the assembly), then rewrite the include to kick the designer into motion. I'm pretty confident this is the cause of the problem, but if not:
- [Fiddle with your `src` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677453/designer-cs-issues-with-using-user-control-in-visual-studio) and check in the *.designer file what type is defined.
- Define it manually in your code-behind file instead of letting the designer do it.

Comment: I have DNN\bin\DotNetNuke.Web.DDRMenu.dll as reference in my project and in the code behind using DotNetNuke.Web.DDRMenu is set. But the designer assigns the wrong type. I will try to define it manually or check the designer

Comment: @spankmaster79 It does that sometimes, especially when you are working in a project that doesn't live in DNN itself. You could also cast the control manually to SkinObject if you don't want to fight the designer

Comment: I've deleted it from the designer and casted it manually to SkinObject in my code behind. Now it compiles and works. Big thx