# Why Does DotNetNuke TextEditor Control Break After Editing Module .ascx File

Tags: dotnetnuke

When building a custom module for DotNetNuke, I have run into this annoying issue whenever I need to edit an `.ascx` control that makes use of the DotNetNuke TextEditor control.

If I make any change to the `.ascx` file, the control's `designer` file reverts the control's definition back to `System.Web.UI.UserControl` after the change is made.  If I manually change the definition back to `DotNetNuke.UI.UserControls.TextEditor`, I can successfully build until I make another change in the `.ascx` control again.  I have searched the DNN forums and Stack Overflow, but have not found a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

After much searching, I have found the answer via the following post:

[designer.cs issues with using user control in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677453/designer-cs-issues-with-using-user-control-in-visual-studio)

Basically, move the "TextEditor" entries that are usually placed in the "designer.cs" file into the code behind file.  Once this is done, you can edit the .ascx controls without the annoying need to manually edit the "designer.cs" files repeatedly.

Comment: Please do not post links to [duplicate answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/206345). Instead, consider other actions that could help future users find the answer they need, as described in the linked post.